# Flutter "ChangeNotifierProxyProvider have an error. error: "The named parameter 'builder' isn't defined. "

Tags: flutter, builder

main.dart file ChangeNotifierProxyProvider having issues builder method is not defined.

```
 ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Orders>(
      builder: (ctx, auth, previousOrders) => Orders(
        auth.token,
        auth.userId,
        previousOrders == null ? [] : previousOrders.orders,
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
      create: (_) => Products('', '', []),
      update: (_, auth, prevProducts) {
        return Products(
          auth.token,
          auth.userId,
          prevProducts == null ? [] : prevProducts.items,
        );
      },
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Their is no argument like **builder** in **[ChangeNotifierProxyProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProxyProvider-class.html)**, that’s why you are getting that error.

In ChangeNotifierProxyProvider you have to provide create, update and child.

Here, in create you can create your object and in update you can specify when to change provider's value, when notifier depends on some other model.

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<MyModel, MyChangeNotifier>(
   create: (_) => MyChangeNotifier(),
   update: (_, myModel, myNotifier) => myNotifier
       ..update(myModel),
    child: ...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

**ChangeNotifierProvider** supported builder parameter but migration from **v3.x.0 to v4.0.0+** some parameters are changed and builder is one of them.

Instead of that the ***initialBuilder*** should be replaced by **create**.

builder of ***"proxy" providers*** should be replaced by **update**

builder of ***classical providers*** should be replaced by **create**.

Answer (score 0):

with `provider: ^5.0.0` this also should work as expected

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
  create: (ctx) {
    return Products();
  },
  update: (ctx, auth, prev) {
    return Products()
      ..setAuthToken(auth.token ?? '')
      ..setItems(prev?.items ?? []);
  },
),
```